# jquery dialog - which button opened the dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, jquery-ui-dialog

In the example below, how can you use the event and ui objects to detect which link opened the dialog?  Can't seem to get $(event.target).attr("title"); to work properly, and I'm having trouble finding documentation on the 'ui object that is passed.  Thanks!

```
$("#dialog_support_option_form").dialog({
   link_title = $(event.target).attr("title");
   alert(link_title);
});


$("a").live("click", function() {
    btn_rel = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(btn_rel).dialog("open");
});

<a class="btn pencil" rel="#dialog_support_option_form" title="Edit Support Option">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Can anyone clear up how the 'event' and 'ui' objects can be used correctly in relation to the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that detection in the `click` event that opens it, you can then use it and set something in the dialog, alert it...whatever you're looking to do with the value, like this:

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
  var btn_rel = $(this).attr("rel");
  $(btn_rel).dialog("open");
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  //alert(title);
  //or:
  //$("#dialog_support_option_form .something").text(title);
  //whatever you want to do with it :)
});
```

Comment: Gosh, I just thought JQuery would have a prettier way of passing the variable.  Guess this will have to do.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

parents() returns multiple records use parent() instead.

Comment: I just simplified the code in my post to just try to get the title of the button, just ran a test and I can't even get the title of the button...